# Direct Dynamic URL in root to a location within template

Tags: url-rewriting, urls

I needed to have dynamic URLs created once a user (say Organization) submitted a registration form where the URL would be domain.com/organizations/organization-name/dashboard/

The "organization-name" is part of the registration form that gets checked by Ajax for duplication. (this is already accomplished )

The problem I have is that the URL is getting created in root not within the theme.  So I'm getting a blank screen.

My question is, how can I extend my current theme to these dynamic URLs that get created.
How do I place my current theme's header/footer within this code:

```
function arfGenURL($orgName)
{
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$dir = "organizations/" . $orgName . "/dashboard/";
echo var_dump(mkdir($dir,0777,TRUE));
$content = "<html><head><title>Organization Dashboard |</title></head><body></body></html>";
$fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/' . $dir . "/index.php","wb");
fwrite($fp,$content);
fclose($fp);
print_r(error_get_last());
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: in the code above, what can I put in $content that pull header and footer of active theme?  ...any ideas folks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't much "dynamic" about actually creating folder tree and index files in it. What you have right now is completely tangential to your WordPress installation.

In a nutshell, if you need to integrate this with WordPress, you have two approaches:

1. Load WordPress core in your code. This can be done with including `wp-load.php` and some fine–tuning, but it's pretty advanced technique (done properly).
2. Load your code in WordPress. This will involve getting it in line with WP mechanics and likely using [Rewrite API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API) to deal with links.

Either is quite involved really. Keeping standalone functionality separate might actually be quite practical, if you are not willing to spent time on adapting it properly.

Comment: Hey Rarst, thanks for your thoughts. Can you suggest any other way of creating the dynamic URL as described if I decide not to go this rout that I'm at?

Comment: How do you mean by "standalone"?

Comment: I mean that in current state your code doesn't seem to use any of WP functionality. It pretty much does things in a way that goes _against_ WP functionality (time zone stuff, writing files...).

Comment: If I were to have this load to Wordpress, how do you suggest to get it going?  I had a programmer to do this for me but obviously WP was not considered.  I want learn the mechanics, so any direction will greatly be appreciated.

Comment: As per answer — different approaches to this. Maybe through loading core, maybe through rewrite, maybe something different altogether. Creating custom URLs in WP is far from friendly...